# How to animate a transparent PNG on top of my activity?

Tags: android

Two things I need to achieve:

1) Show a semi-transparent PNG on top of my UI (my activity is a combination of layouts, buttons etc.)

2) Animate the position of the PNG from the center of the activity outwards at a specific angle...

Anyone have advise on what I should be looking at to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this for Animation:

- [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)
- [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm)

And in case of `png` image, you can use the `Android:alpha=""` property for setting opacity, also `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in case you are having trouble with the transparency of `png`